# express middleware after response

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I've had a problem with middleware function which is launching on finish execution of main function from endpoint. Here is my middleware:

```
export const someMiddleware = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => {
    res.on("finish", () => {
        //here
    })
    next();
}
```

I am having trouble getting the data that was sent to the client from the request handled by this middleware, can anyone tell me how to get the response body that is sent to the client inside the `on ()` callback?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're trying to do something that Express does not support.  The response data that is sent to the client is not saved anywhere for you to access after its sent.  It's sent out the response stream and is gone once its sent to the client.  You could "watch" what is sent to the client in real time by hooking into the response stream and seeing what is sent to that stream.  Keep in mind that there are lots of ways to write to a stream and data may be sent to the stream in pieces, not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite painful with Express. One way to handle this is to override the `send` and `write` functions, and capture the output this way.

It's not impossible to do this, other middlewares like a gzip middleware would do this too.

A frustration with this limitation has eventually lead me to [write my own framework](https://github.com/curveball/core), so I get where you are coming from.